# How to not display child div when outside parent div border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a child `div` to not display when it overextends its parent's boundaries.
Like this:

[image]

The child `div` (red border) is bigger than the parent (blue border) and the parent "crops" it when it goes outside the parent's borders.

**Note:** I don't want the red border, it's just there to show how the child is bigger than the parent.

Is this possible?
Here's what I've got so far:

```css
#contain {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px blue dashed;
  background-color: rgba(60, 10, 10, .5);
  padding: 20px;
}

#big {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, .5);
}
```

```html
<div id='contain'>
  <div id='big'></div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkzzwjm1/2/)

Comment: Please note that you should include your code in the question itself, a JSFiddle is not sufficient as the link may die leaving the question without context. Hmm, the problem is that if you use `overflow: hidden;` on `#contain` the `border` will be cut off. Do you always know the `width`, `height` and `padding` that will be used on these elements? If the `#big` `div` had content (i.e. text or other elements) in it would you expect it to be cropped?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes the border isn't needed, it was there just to display that the div kept going. My mistake.

Comment: In that case @Kragalon `overflow: hidden;` is all you will need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use this style:

```
#contain{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px blue dashed;
  background-color:rgba(60, 10, 10, .5);
  padding:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent div.

```css
#contain{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px blue dashed;
  background-color:rgba(60, 10, 10, .5);
  padding:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#big{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px red solid;
  background-color:rgba(30, 30, 30, .5);
}
```

```html
<div id='contain'>
  <div id='big'>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

just add `overflow:hidden;` to your style.